# Android Studio: setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android

I have two AppCompatActivitys, both should have an onItemClickListener, but one of them doesn't do anything on click. I've just added a Toast for test reason, later on it should call a function to delete an item from list (with an ajax request)

What am I doing wrong?

I have made custom list and custom adapter for this - I know, I am new to Android Studio, but the other Activity works fine, and I cant find any differences.

`public class ActivityListofProducts extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressDialog pd;

    SharedPreferences preferences;
    String userid;
    String session;
    String list_id = "-1"; // or other values
    String appVersion = "";

    private ArrayList<listProductItem> myProducts = new ArrayList<listProductItem>();
    private ArrayList<listProductItem> groceryFilterProducts = new ArrayList<listProductItem>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        handleIntent(getIntent());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_products);

        this.setTitle(getString(R.string.grocery_list));

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.refreshLayout);

        if (b != null)
            list_id = b.getString("list_id");

        Toast.makeText(this, "List to open " + " " + list_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        preferences =
                getSharedPreferences(this.getPackageName(), this.MODE_PRIVATE);
        userid = preferences.getString("userid", "");
        session = preferences.getString("session", "");
        appVersion = preferences.getString("appVersion", "");

        getData();

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        getData();
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void getData() {
        AsyncTask<String, String, String> Task_GetListofProducts = new Task_GetListofProducts();
        Task_GetListofProducts.execute("https://get-some-json.com");
    }

    public void initListofProducts(String jsonString) {
        Log.i("jsonString",jsonString);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonString);

            JSONObject jsonListMode = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("list");
            String ListName = jsonListMode.optString("name");
            this.setTitle(ListName);

            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                int item_amount = jsonChildNode.optInt("item_amount");
                int id = jsonChildNode.optInt("id");
                String item_name = jsonChildNode.optString("item_name",">Name<");
                int done = jsonChildNode.optInt("done", 0);
                String timestamp = jsonChildNode.optString("timestamp", "");
                String item_scale = jsonChildNode.optString("item_scale", "x");
                String img = jsonChildNode.optString("img", "x");
                double bestprice = jsonChildNode.optDouble("bestprice");
                //int oitems = jsonChildNode.optInt("oitems", 0);
                //int shared = jsonChildNode.optInt("shared", 0);

                String outPut = "item_amount:"+ item_amount +" id:"+ id +" item_name:"+ item_name +" done:"+ done +" timestamp:"+ timestamp +" item_scale:"+ item_scale +" img:"+ img;
                Log.i("outPut",outPut);
                
                myProducts.add(new listProductItem(id, item_name, item_amount, item_scale, img, done, timestamp, bestprice));
            }

            final ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.grocery_list_of_products);
            lv.setAdapter(new listofProductsAdapter(this, myProducts));

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                    /*
                    !! HERE is my problem. This Code seems not to be executed !!
                    */
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityListofProducts.this, "Should handle click now.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void setProductDone(int pid, int done) {
        String url = "put-some-json.com";
        new ActivityListofProducts.Task_SetProductDone().execute(url);

    }

    private class Task_SetProductDone extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = new ProgressDialog(ActivityListofProducts.this);
            pd.setMessage("Please wait");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            Log.i("doInBackground",params.toString());

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);   //here you will get whole response...... :-)

                }

                return buffer.toString();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityListofProducts.this, "No Internet?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pd.isShowing()) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }

            Log.i("onPostExecute", result);
        }
    }

    private class Task_GetListofProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = new ProgressDialog(ActivityListofProducts.this);
            pd.setMessage("Please wait");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();

            myProducts = new ArrayList<listProductItem>(); //empty list
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            Log.i("doInBackground",params.toString());

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);   //here you will get whole response...... :-)

                }

                return buffer.toString();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pd.isShowing()) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }

            initListofProducts(result);
        }
    }

    private class Task_FindProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = new ProgressDialog(ActivityListofProducts.this);
            pd.setMessage("Please wait");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();

            myProducts = new ArrayList<listProductItem>(); //empty list
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            Log.i("doInBackground",params.toString());

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);   //here you will get whole response...... :-)

                }

                return buffer.toString();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pd.isShowing()) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }

            setFilterProducts(result);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Are you sure that `initListofProducts` (and the corresponding call to `lv.setOnItemClickListener`) are actually run?

Comment: @TylerV: Yes, I am. initListofProducts parses the json string and fills the list with content.
Adding a <code>Log.i("test","Here I am");</code> before the line of 'lv.setOnItemClickListener' also gets fired.

Comment: Instead of just pasting your entire activity here, please make a *minimum, complete* example that someone else could run to see the same behavior. This means make a new project and include only the click listener part that is causing you problems, verify that you see the same behavior in that simplified problem, then edit the question to include the necessary classes and XML files for someone else to be able to run it too.